# Magento 2 Admin 404

Tags: magento2

I have tried all the possible ways listed on other answers.

So my issue is that i'm using Ubuntu and i have tried all possible ways to fix 404 but none of them worked for me. Following ways i tried before

1. [Apache rewrite](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy#answer-120109)
2. [Store ID and website ids](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87038/magento-2-error-404-not-found-at-magento-2-admin-login-page)
3. .Htacess on root folder
4. Clear Cache
5. Upgrade
6. Re Compile

There are no error logged in logs or reports.

What could be else, Advance thanks for any help.

Comment: [1] Please follow http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89634/after-successful-installation-admin-url-is-returning-a-404 or https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Magento-2-Localhost-Admin-url-returning-404-error/td-p/21435 [2]  Check for folder permission [3] Check for Admin URL is correct or not [4] Last try to do new installation

Comment: I have tried all these methods before no success, may be will go to least new installation, there might be some solution for this issue, which i m interested to figure it out first

Answer (score 1):

Please try Below solutions

1) delete `var/cache` and `var/session` folder

2) go to database `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites'` and make it 0

3) then enter url in your browser `magento_base_url/index.php/your_admin_url`

try again and let me know if you face any issue

also try to run this command after all this in your terminal

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I do all these before not helpful

Comment: go to `app/etc/env.php` rename this file and your magento installetion start again

Comment: Is this safe way to do this?

Comment: Rename this file and if anything break then just revert this file as orignal

Comment: should i need to used same database or new one?

Comment: If there is not much database changes then you can create new db and delete old one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45083/discussion-between-adeel-ishfaq-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: I have already done these steps but it didn't work.

Comment: have you restart  the magento installetion

Comment: yeah i do it didn't work with old database

Comment: Ok its working with new db?

Comment: Yes its working with new db, But i have a lot of data in old db.

Comment: you can copy those tables from new db table

Comment: will they work if i simply copy them to new one, and what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Yes it will work no worrys